# Pandas column replace $ and letter from rows

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column with currency values. All have a leading '$' and some have a trailing F. Trying to remove the charcters using replace with pandas.

My data is:

```
$4.00F
$21.00
$6.00
$6.00
$5.50
$13.00
$4.60F
```

This is my code using replace. However, it removes no characters at all.

```
df["Price"].replace("^/$$[F]", "", regex=True)
```

Where is my regex incorrect?

Comment: You could use `.lstrip('$')` and `.rstrip('F')`, if it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The `^/$$[F]` pattern matches a string that starts with `/`, then makes sure the string ends right after `/` (twice) and then the regex engine searches for `F` (after the end of string). As you see, the pattern has no sense.

You can use

```py
df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.replace(r"^\$|F$", "", regex=True)
```

This will remove a `$` at the start and `F` at the end.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhpdHh/1).

If you do not care where the `$` and `F` are, you may use

```py
df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.replace(r"[$F]+", "", regex=True)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhpdHh/2) where `[$F]+` matches one or more `F` or `$` chars.

Also, consider the classic pattern removing any chars other than digits and dots:

```py
df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.replace(r"[^0-9.]+", "", regex=True)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhpdHh/3).

Answer (score 1):

In this instance you can simply avoid any regex and use `.strip('$F')`:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.strip('$F')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove any character (not just '$' and 'F') that is not a number at the start and the end of your string:

```
>>> df['Price'].str.replace(r'^[^\d+]|[^\d+]$', '', regex=True)
0     4.00
1    21.00
2     6.00
3     6.00
4     5.50
5    13.00
6     4.60
Name: Price, dtype: object
```